# AngularJS $http request inside service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-service

I'm trying to get some data from a Service into a Controller and I keep get an undefined variable.

```
angular
    .module("classes")
    .service("MyService", function ($http) {

        this.foo;
        $http.get("/classes/all").then(function (response) {
            this.fighters = response.data;
            this.foo = this.fighters;
            console.log(this.foo);
        });
        console.log(this.foo);

    })
```

When I run this I get on the console, by this order,  line 11 is undefined and then line 9 returns me the array.

And when in the controller I try to get the variable foo, it also says undefined.

```
$scope.fooFighters = MyService.foo;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because of asynchronous execution of your API call. I would suggest you to rewrite the code to use a factory that will return a promise object. No need to bring unnecessary variables.

```
angular.module("classes").factory("MyService", function($http) {
    return {
        fighters: function() {
            return $http.get("/classes/all").then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

And in your controller, you can get the value by injecting the service in the controller and then by referencing it like

```
 MyService.fighters().then(function(data){
   $scope.fooFighters = data;
  });
```

Comment: if add console.log($scope.fooFighters); right after in the controller. I get first undefined for the variable in the controller and then I get the array from the service console.log(this.fighters);

Comment: Try the above code. Change your service to a factory to return a promise object.

Comment: I jus tried it. it keeps logging "undefined" on the console

Comment: Where are you  printing $scope.fooFighters? You should put console inside then

Comment: Ohhh!! Ir has to be inside of MyService.fighters ()?so the whole controller depending on that service will have to inside of that too. Is this a good practice?

Comment: This is how we use a service or a factory to avoid the problem of getting undefined coz of asyn execution. You can search and mostly everywhere it is like this.

Comment: I see! Thank you! :)
Is it possible to have multiple returns in the same factory for different $http routes?

Comment: Yes, you just have to create different methods or properties and return it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

because it will take some time to load the ajax/http request data after that line 9 will work. So if you want to work with ajax/http data then you should write code/function inside

```
$http.get("/classes/all").then(function (response) {
        // do something
    });
```

Comment: The problem is If I want to access it in the controller. It will only do the http after running the controller